# Hibernate kills PostgreSQL Server by sending weired query

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I'm executing this little piece of code:

```
currentExamTemplateId = 7l;
currentStudentId = 806l;

TemplateStudent ts = templateStudentRepository.findByTemplateAndStudent(currentExamTemplateId, currentStudentId);

currentExamTemplateId = 11l;
currentStudentId = 555l;

ts = templateStudentRepository.findByTemplateAndStudent(currentExamTemplateId, currentStudentId);
```

The repository query looks this way:

```
@Query("select a from TemplateStudent a where a.examTemplate.examTemplateId=:examTemplateId and a.student.studentId=:studentId")
    TemplateStudent findByTemplateAndStudent(@Param("examTemplateId") Long examTemplateId, @Param("studentId") Long studentId);
```

While executing the first findByTemplateAndStudent call, nothing weird happens, the SQL Server delivers the correct data and the SQL statement looks quite normal:

```
2015-11-11 16:09:37 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
                o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
Hibernate: 
    select
        templatest0_.templateStudentId as template1_16_,
        templatest0_.examtemplateid as examtemp2_16_,
        templatest0_.studentid as studenti3_16_ 
    from
        TemplateStudent templatest0_ 
    where
        templatest0_.examtemplateid=? 
        and templatest0_.studentid=?
2015-11-11 16:09:37 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
                o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/livekorrektur_dev]
2015-11-11 16:09:37 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
                o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

But after executing the second findByTemplateAndStudent, Hibernate sends two SQL queries. First one looks normal as well.

```
2015-11-11 16:09:57 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
                o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
Hibernate: 
    select
        templatest0_.templateStudentId as template1_16_,
        templatest0_.examtemplateid as examtemp2_16_,
        templatest0_.studentid as studenti3_16_ 
    from
        TemplateStudent templatest0_ 
    where
        templatest0_.examtemplateid=? 
        and templatest0_.studentid=?
2015-11-11 16:09:57 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
                o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/livekorrektur_dev]
Hibernate: 
    select
        examtempla0_.examTemplateId as examTemp1_6_0_,
        examtempla0_.examId as examId3_6_0_,
        examtempla0_.name as name2_6_0_,
        exam1_.examId as examId1_4_1_,
        exam1_.correctionEnd as correcti2_4_1_,
        exam1_.correctionStart as correcti3_4_1_,
        exam1_.created as created4_4_1_,
        exam1_.gradeLevelId as gradeLe11_4_1_,
        exam1_.name as name5_4_1_,
        exam1_.semester as semester6_4_1_,
        exam1_.shortName as shortNam7_4_1_,
        exam1_.state as state8_4_1_,
        exam1_.studentInfo as studentI9_4_1_,
        exam1_.tightRange as tightRa10_4_1_,
        correctors2_.examId as examId3_4_2_,
        actor3_.actorId as actorId2_3_2_,
        actor3_.actorId as actorId1_0_3_,
        actor3_.created as created2_0_3_,
        actor3_.email as email3_0_3_,
        actor3_.enabled as enabled4_0_3_,
        actor3_.firstName as firstNam5_0_3_,
        actor3_.lastLogin as lastLogi6_0_3_,
        actor3_.lastName as lastName7_0_3_,
        actor3_.login as login8_0_3_,
        actor3_.password as password9_0_3_,
        roles4_.actorId as actorId2_0_4_,
        role5_.roleId as roleId3_1_4_,
        role5_.roleId as roleId1_11_5_,
        role5_.description as descript2_11_5_,
        role5_.displayName as displayN3_11_5_,
        role5_.name as name4_11_5_,
        exercises6_.examId as examId4_4_6_,
        exercises6_.exerciseId as exercise1_7_6_,
        exercises6_.exerciseId as exercise1_7_7_,
        exercises6_.examId as examId4_7_7_,
        exercises6_.maxPoints as maxPoint2_7_7_,
        exercises6_.name as name3_7_7_,
        exercises6_.parentExerciseId as parentEx5_7_7_,
        exercise7_.exerciseId as exercise1_7_8_,
        exercise7_.examId as examId4_7_8_,
        exercise7_.maxPoints as maxPoint2_7_8_,
        exercise7_.name as name3_7_8_,
        exercise7_.parentExerciseId as parentEx5_7_8_,
        gradelevel8_.gradeLevelId as gradeLev1_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.fourPointZero as fourPoin2_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.onePointSeven as onePoint3_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.onePointThree as onePoint4_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.onePointZero as onePoint5_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.threePointSeven as threePoi6_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.threePointThree as threePoi7_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.threePointZero as threePoi8_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.twoPointSeven as twoPoint9_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.twoPointThree as twoPoin10_8_9_,
        gradelevel8_.twoPointZero as twoPoin11_8_9_,
        participan9_.examId as examId2_4_10_,
        student10_.studentId as studentI4_5_10_,
        student10_.studentId as studentI1_14_11_,
        student10_.enrolmentNumber as enrolmen2_14_11_,
        student10_.firstName as firstNam3_14_11_,
        student10_.lastName as lastName4_14_11_,
        exercises11_.examTemplateId as examTemp2_6_12_,
        exercise12_.exerciseId as exercise3_15_12_,
        exercise12_.exerciseId as exercise1_7_13_,
        exercise12_.examId as examId4_7_13_,
        exercise12_.maxPoints as maxPoint2_7_13_,
        exercise12_.name as name3_7_13_,
        exercise12_.parentExerciseId as parentEx5_7_13_,
        students13_.examTemplateId as examTemp2_6_14_,
        student14_.studentId as studentI3_16_14_,
        student14_.studentId as studentI1_14_15_,
        student14_.enrolmentNumber as enrolmen2_14_15_,
        student14_.firstName as firstNam3_14_15_,
        student14_.lastName as lastName4_14_15_ 
    from
        ExamTemplate examtempla0_ 
    left outer join
        Exam exam1_ 
            on examtempla0_.examId=exam1_.examId 
    left outer join
        Corrector correctors2_ 
            on exam1_.examId=correctors2_.examId 
    left outer join
        Actor actor3_ 
            on correctors2_.actorId=actor3_.actorId 
    left outer join
        ActorRole roles4_ 
            on actor3_.actorId=roles4_.actorId 
    left outer join
        Role role5_ 
            on roles4_.roleId=role5_.roleId 
    left outer join
        Exercise exercises6_ 
            on exam1_.examId=exercises6_.examId 
    left outer join
        Exercise exercise7_ 
            on exercises6_.parentExerciseId=exercise7_.exerciseId 
    left outer join
        GradeLevel gradelevel8_ 
            on exam1_.gradeLevelId=gradelevel8_.gradeLevelId 
    left outer join
        ExamParticipant participan9_ 
            on exam1_.examId=participan9_.examId 
    left outer join
        Student student10_ 
            on participan9_.studentId=student10_.studentId 
    left outer join
        TemplateExercise exercises11_ 
            on examtempla0_.examTemplateId=exercises11_.examTemplateId 
    left outer join
        Exercise exercise12_ 
            on exercises11_.exerciseId=exercise12_.exerciseId 
    left outer join
        TemplateStudent students13_ 
            on examtempla0_.examTemplateId=students13_.examTemplateId 
    left outer join
        Student student14_ 
            on students13_.studentId=student14_.studentId 
    where
        examtempla0_.examTemplateId=? 
    order by
        student10_.studentId
```

The second statement uses a lot of joins and I have no idea, why this statement is called. By sending this query to PostgreSQL, the server uses a lot of CPU / IO and is unable to respond (I've waited 5 minutes so far).

Does anyone has an idea, whereby this problem is caused?

Comment: Your entity must have plenty of eagerly-loaded associations with entities having plenty of eagerly-loaded associations, etc.

Comment: The entity TemplateStudent only contains two eagerly fetched lists, both containing not a single eagerly fetched field. Nevertheless, removing the FetchType.EAGER from both lists, raises the "LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session"-Problem at a different part of the app, which was solved before by adding FetchType.EAGER.

Comment: I hope you're aware that OneToOne and ManyToOne associations are eager by default. I'd bet that you have many such associations, and not just 2 eagerly fetched lists. Anyway, setting an association to EAGER is not the right way to solve your exception: it forces Hibernate to load the association **every time**, even if you don't need it. Initialize the association when you need it, before closing the session. Or use a query that explicitely fetches the required associations.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How can I initialize the association? I'm not aware of the fact, that I'm closing any kind of session. (BTW: You were right, there are more OneToOne and ManyToOne connections, that weren't explicitly marked as eager. Is there a possibility of causing a loop?)

Comment: Another remark: The DB is very small. Just in case the whole DB is loaded because every single object is loaded, this shouldn't take more then 5 minutes.

Comment: You can initialize the association by calling any method on the collection, or by explicitely calling Hibernate.initialize(). The session is closed as soon as the transaction ends, by default.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now I'm getting the following error when tying to initialize the collection: "org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session" Do you have any idea how to fix this? Haven't found anything to solve this by now, but I'm continuing to search.

Comment: You need to initialize it from **inside** the transaction.

Comment: Now, I've marked my controller with @Transactional and it worked. Do you mean that with "initialize it from inside the transaction"?

Comment: Yes, for example. If you start a new transaction every time you call a repository method, something is wrong. The transaction should start on a service or even controller call.

Comment: While that query is horrible, PostgreSQL shouldn't have any real issues with it. Sure, it'll slow the server down a bit and take a while to run, but PostgreSQL should continue to serve other queries fine. Maybe you've set `work_mem` way too high, so it's swapping, or something?

Comment: I was now able to remove all EAGER annotations and the server is running quite fast now. Thanks a lot!